# ASP.NET MVC 3 application with AD environnement

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory

I'm developping an application with ASP.NET MVC3 and I have to give an access to client to see some files, this files are in local server and change permanantly
We are working in active directory environement
I need to have an Idea how to give this acces in secure manner. Do I need to create a user in read only and authenticate him from the app
I need to imagine the scenario and how make it work
Some Ideas please

Comment: Can you give the client users in your AD?

Answer (score 1):

Since your are using Active directory you could hookup your application with Windows Authentication.

Then you could set IIS to use impersonation and apply group policies to the folder you want the application to acces.

[Here is a nice tutorial from Microsoft.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)